Running Azure Load Testing Service in unsupported regions
Azure Load Testing service is currently not available in every Azure region. E.g. Azure Load Testing Service is not available in US-WEST, but available in US-WEST2 and US-WEST3.
Now, if a customer who has a deployment restriction policy specific to US-WEST region, whose customers are also residing in US-WEST region only, want to run Azure Load Testing for the workload (Web App, APIs) deployed within US-WEST region, what is the solution?
Because if you host Azure Load Testing service in US-WEST2 or US-WEST3 region to URL test the WebApp/API deployed in US-WEST region, it will add additional latencies.
